# html form array to JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm having a dynamic html form containing several values, what I need is to add form data to JSON and post it to php page for insertion to mysql.

Form:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" id="p" />
<input type="text" name="manuf[]" id="k" size="3" />
<input type="text" name="item_pr[]" id="ka" size="10" />
<input type="text" name="price" id="su" size="10" disabled="disabled"/><br />
```

First tried to create JS array but cant figure out how get all values in one code row and how to convert to json and post to php:

```
var elementai = document.getElementsByName('name[]');
          for (var i = 0, j = elementai.length; i < j; i++) {
          var elementas = elementai[i];
          alert(elementas.value);
          }
```

Comment: I got hammered once for offering a jQuery solution where it wasn't asked for. So with that in mind check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11419600/144665) out.

Comment: Why use JSON? What is wrong with application/x-www-form-urlencoded data? Especially since you are already using the naming convention that allows PHP to handle multiple sets of inputs with the same name in that encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can use jQuery for it as it is easy to use and less code to write. Though i am giving both solutions here.

**In JavaScript :**

```
$.fn.extractObject = function() {
  var accum = {};
  function add(accum, namev, value) {
    if (namev.length == 1)
      accum[namev[0]] = value;
    else {
      if (accum[namev[0]] == null)
        accum[namev[0]] = {};
      add(accum[namev[0]], namev.slice(1), value);
    }
  }; 
  this.find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
    add(accum, $(this).attr('name').split('.'), $(this).val());
  });
  return accum;
}
// ...

var object = $('#testformId').extractObject();
console.log(object);
```

​Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G2XVq/) : http://jsfiddle.net/G2XVq/

**In jQuery :**

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
        return false;
    });
});​
```

(jQuery portion taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery))

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/) : http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/

**for posting the data to php through javascript:**

```
 var str_json = JSON.stringify(myObject) //gives me the JSON string.

// AJAX XMLHttpRequest object in Javascript to send data to the server:
request= new XMLHttpRequestObject()
request.open("POST", "Phppage.php")
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true)
request.send(str_json)
```

Comment: Overkill to use jQuery for this one instance.

Comment: Even i don't suggest for using jquery for one instance only.That's why i have added javascript code here..

Comment: Your top example isn't pure JavaScript. :$

Answer (score 2):

The solution below utilizes the [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function from jQuery to minimize the amount of code required to accurately reach your desired result.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="p" /> 
<input type="text" name="manuf" id="k" size="3" /> <input type="text" name="item_pr" id="ka" size="10" /> 
<input type="text" name="price" id="su" size="10" disabled="disabled"/>
<br /> 
<input type="button" id="go" value="Go >>" onclick="createJSONObject()" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
function createJSONObject(){
    var formValues = $('input[type=text]');
    var obj = {};
    $.map(formValues, function(n, i) {
        obj[n.name] = $(n).val();
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mBLkH/

The above code creates a jQuery object of your `input` elements and then maps the `name` attribute and `value` of each element to the `obj` object variable.  It then utilizes `JSON.stringify(obj)` to format the object into a viewable context.

Comment: Overkill to use jQuery for this one instance.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is over kill on this one.

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/nTnhW/

Pure JavaScript:

```
var input_ids = ['p','k','ka','su'];

for (var i = 0, j = input_ids.length; i < j; i++) {
    var element = document.getElementById(input_ids[i]);
    alert(element.value);
}​
```

Comment: this is perfect. how to post it to php page? $.post should be in for cycle?

Comment: if there is going to be 50 form elements, then Is it good way to put all in input_id array one by one?????????

Comment: @NishuTayal With the HTML we were given this is my solution. Had we been given a form tag maybe with an ID then that would influence the answer. I work with what is asked for and what is given.

Comment: I know it's been a while, PMJI - I am curious as to why you say jQuery is overkill.  The Proof link seems to only prove that the js works - not why it's better.  TIA for any info on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get your text inputs and you know the form's id:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('myForm').getElementsByTagName('input');
var params = {};
for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    var curr = inputs[i];
    if(curr.getAttribute('type')==='text')){
        params[curr.getAttribute('name')] = curr.value;
    }
}
```

Using jQuery to post:

```
$.post('myUrl',params,function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

Or with straight javascript:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567146/1081941